# is_file or file_exists not working in apache but in CLI

Tags: php, apache2, debian

I have a very strange behavior with is_file() or file_exists() function.

```
<?php 
    $nfsFile = '/mnt/nfsdir/file.txt';
    var_dump(is_file($nfsFile));
?>
```

this code returns FALSE all the time, but:

`$#php -r 'var_dump(is_file('/mnt/nfsdir/file.txt'));'`

returns TRUE, which is correct.

I'm running Debian Squeeze, Apache 2.2.15 and PHP 5.3.2-1.

I'm not in safe mode, the directory /mnt/nfsdir/ and all files are in 777, www-data user can ls /mnt/nfsdir/  so I'm a bite out of idea now.

Any suggestion are welcome!

Comment: If you know the file exists (because you've created it during testing, of course), what's the result of trying to do, say, `file_get_contents` on the file?

Comment: Is your path absolute or relative? If relative then the CWD is likely to be different when running from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks realy like a server config issue to me.

Maybe test if echo `exec('ls /mnt/nfsdir/file.txt');` works.

I don't think so. Cause it seams, even if www-data can access the file, PHP is not allowed to access it.

But if `exec('ls /mnt/nfsdir/file.txt');` works this could be a solution for you.

Otherwise I would have a look at the server config again.

Comment: Yes, in fact open_basedir must be set to 'none' even if your are not in safe mode if you want to have access to any files. Changing open_basedir=none resolved the problem, but I assume that it's not very secure.

Comment: Well.. you can make sure, all of your open(), exec(), etc. statements don't allow your users to open/exec any file. If the user can decide wich file to open, make sure to prepend a basedir and to disallow "../", this way your application should be as secure as with open_basedir set.